# How to call the increment/decrement function on a nullable field | Laravel | increment | decrement function

Tags: laravel, database-migration

I have an integer field, and the default value of the field is null.

***Migration***

```
Schema::table('servers', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('retry_ssl_renew')->nullable()->after('ssl_validity');
});
```

I am using Laravel's default [increment-and-decrement](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#increment-and-decrement) function but because of the nullable field, the value is not changed.

When I set the default value of the field as 0, then it starts working. So is there any way we can call the increment function of Laravel on the nullable field? i.e

```
Schema::table('servers', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('retry_ssl_renew')->default(0)->after('ssl_validity');
});
```

Use case:- Most of my team members already create queries based on a null value, if I go with the solution(like set default as 0) then they have to change their condition. I am looking for a smart way.

Comment: think about this: what will be the result of `null + 1` OR `null++` OR `++null`? So, you need to handle this before calling increment or decrement...so if you must work with null, your best bet maybe using a traditional update.

Comment: But I think Laravel should handle this. I mean if we allow an integer value as nullable then the function related to the integer should work as expected.

Comment: Well this is a completely different discussion, but for the sake of argument, I disagree that Laravel should handle this at the framework level. `nullable` integer column is a mysql thing. `increment` and `decrement` are just helper functions that run a mysql update query. I would say that these type of use cases should be handled at the development level.

Answer (score 0):

You could for instance overwrite the increment/decrement function on your model

```php
    protected function increment($column, $amount = 1, array $extra = [])
    {
        if ($this->getAttribute($column) === null) {
            $this->setAttribute($column, 0);
            $this->save();
        }

        return parent::increment($column, $amount, $extra);
    }
```